# rich:clientId within nested datatables returns wrong clientId

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I use RF 4.2.0 and I have the following situation:

```
    <rich:dataTable id="table1" var="..">
    ....
     <rich:column>
       <rich:dataTable id="table2" var="..">
       ...
        <rich:column>
         <h:outputLabel id="myLabel"/>
         <h:outputText value="#{rich:clientId('myLabel')}" />
        </rich:column>
      </rich:dataTable>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

clientId shows always the same id table1:XX:table2:YY:myLabel where XX=latest Row Index for table1 and YY=latest Row Index for table2. Do you know if this is a bug or is something wrong in what I do?

Thanks!